# Getting 403 http error when calling stripe API from classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, stripe-payments

I am adding a stripe integration to my friends site. I wrote the site in classic asp A LONG TIME AGO. The code below ends up with a 403 forbidden. I was getting a 401 until I passed the Authorization header.

I base64 encoded the Publishable Key. I know I am getting the token back.

```
Dim http: Set http = Server.CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
With http
  Call .Open("POST", "https://api.stripe.com/v1/charges", False)
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
  Call .SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic MyBase64EncodedStripeTestPublishableKey")
  Call .Send("amount=0001&currency=usd&description=Example&source=" & Request.Form("stripeToken"))
End With
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Well as it turns out this code is working nicely. The problem I was having was because I wasn't using the public and private keys properly. When creating the checkout token you use the public key on the client side code and then to complete the charge you use the private key on the server side in the basic authentication.

This line should be

```
Call .SetRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic MyBase64EncodedStripeTestSecretKey")
```

Comment: do you have a full working script to process stripe payments using classic asp? if so, can you please share?